# javascript not loading with admin template in flask

Tags: jquery, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

Using this template 
https://github.com/secondtruth/startmin
live working demo here: 
http://secondtruth.github.io/startmin

The file works perfectly when opened locally in the web browser but when i start it with flask it doesn't load the java script for drop down menus. 
All css and js files from static folder load with 200OK

Fire fox console prints out when accessing through flask.

> Error: Graph container element not found  morris.min.js:6:1340

Here are my files:
home.html

```
 <title>Startmin - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
 <link href="/static/css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Timeline CSS -->
 <link href="/static/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom CSS -->
 <link href="/static/css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
 <link href="/static/css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom Fonts -->
 <link href="/static/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
{% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}  

{% include 'includes/_sidebar.html' %} 

 <div class="starter-template">
{% include 'includes/_messages.html' %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
 </div>



 <!-- /#footer -->
 {% include 'includes/_footer.html' %}
 <!-- /#footer -->

 <!-- /#wrapper -->

 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
 <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
 <script src="/static/js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
 <script src="/static/js/raphael.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/js/morris.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/js/morris-data.js"></script>

 <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
 <script src="/static/js/startmin.js"></script>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i start it with flask it doesn't load the java script for **drop down menus**

That's because you aren't loading the popper.js which is required for all things that pop up or drop down in Bootstrap 4.

Speaking of Bootstrap 4, the template you are linking to (i.e. the live demo) is using `Bootstrap v3.3.2` which is beyond dinosaur age version of Bootstrap. The current Bootstrap 3 version is Bootstrap v3.3.7 and Bootstrap 3, in general, is totally incompatible with Bootstrap 4. (those are about as different as a truck is different from a sports car)